# JavaScript - Return a value of the first property that contains a substring in its name

Tags: javascript

So let's say I have an object:

```
var myObj = {
  blahblah_id1: "some_value",
  blahblah_id2: "some_cool_value",
  blahblah_id3: "even_coooler_value",
  blahblah_id4: "the_dopest_value"
};
```

So if something like this existed in `JS: myObj["*id2"]` would return "some_cool_value". Returning value is not necessarily a string, could be another object.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet?

Comment: should not very difficult to do this. You can do it! Give it a try.

Comment: You'll have to search through the keys and there are several different ways you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints out each value whose key/property name matches `.*id2$` for an object:

```
var myObj = {
    blahblah_id1: "some_value",
    blahblah_id2: "some_cool_value",
    blahblah_id3: "even_coooler_value",
    blahblah_id4: "the_dopest_value"
};

var keys = Object.keys(myObj);
for (var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var key = keys[i];
    if( key.match(/.*id2$/) )
    {
        console.log( myObj[key] );
    }
}
```

Comment: @StanA: Good luck on your project! People here usually prefer if you explain what you're tried so far, so you might want to add that to yours questions next time.